# How to do a raw SQL query with Eloquent DB::connection?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am writing a seed in Laravel that imports data from an old schema.

So I would like to do something like:

```
DB::connection('old')
    ->raw('SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN foo ON...')
    ->each(function($user) {
})
```

Unfortunately it seems neither `get()`, `all()` nor `each()` exist.

The `DB::connection('old')->raw(...)` returns me a `Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression`

The problem with

```
DB::connection('old')
   ->table('users') 
   ->select(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN..'))
   ->get()
```

is that I get a syntax error `SELECT * FROM users from users`. That's why I do not want to select a table, but instead execute a raw query on `old` schema.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#running-queries

Comment: Did you tried without calling the table method? `DB::connection('old')
   ->select(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN..'))
  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Query Builder like this, it will return collection with stdClass.

So you can apply `each` to collection:

```php
DB::connection('old')
   ->table('users')
   ->join('foo', '...')
   ->get()
   ->each(function($user) {}});
```

Or use `DB::select()`, it will return array with stdClass, and use foreach for it:

```php
$users = DB::connection('old')->select('SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN foo ON...');

foreach($users as $user) {
}
```

Comment: So, if my raw query is not a select, I still need to use `select` method?

Comment: @nowox if you want to select the columns you need, you can use it, but in your post, you are using `select *`, you don't need the `select` method for query-builder, it will automatically `select *`